# kafka streams total word count in a message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/quickstart

I had a question on counting words within a message using kafka streams. Essentially, I'd like to count the total number of words, rather than count each instance of a word. 
So, instead of

```
all     1
streams 1
lead    1
to      1
kafka   1
```

I need

```
totalWordCount   5
```

or something similar.

I tried a variety of things to this part of the code :

```
KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
    .count();
```

such as adding `.selectKey((key, value) -> "totalWordCount")` in an attempt to change each key (all, streams, etc) to totalWordCount thinking it'll increment itself 
I've also tried to edit my code using [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/MapFunctionLambdaExample.java) to try and achieve the total word count.

I have not succeeded, and after doing some more [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218885/kafka-streams-for-count-a-total-num), now I am thinking that I have been approaching this incorrectly. It seems as if what I need to do is have 3 topics (I've been working with only 2) and have 2 producers where the last producer somehow takes data from the first producer (that shows the word count of each instance) and basically add up the numbers in order to output the total number of words, but I'm not entirely sure how to approach it. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put the `selectKey()`? The idea is basically correct, but note, that `groupBy()` does set the key, too.

```java
KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> "totalWordCount")
    .count();
```

or (using `groupByKey()` to not change the key before the aggregation)

```java
KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
    .selectKey((key, value) -> "totalWordCount")
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
    .groupByKey()
    .count();
```

Comment: aha! I was putting `selectKey()` after `flatMapValues()` Thanks!

Comment: The actually fix is to change from `groupBy()` to `groupByKey()`. Putting `selectKey()` after `flapMapValue()` works as well -- `flatMapValues()` does not modify the key so changing it before or after is the same here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class FirstStreamApp {

@Bean
public KStream<String,String> process(StreamsBuilder builder){
    KStream<String,String> inputStream = builder.stream("streamIn", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));
    KStream<String,String> upperCaseStream = inputStream.mapValues(value->value.toUpperCase());
   upperCaseStream.to("outTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));

    KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = upperCaseStream.flatMapValues(v-> Arrays.asList(v.split(" "))).selectKey((k, v) -> v).groupByKey().
           count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("counts-store"));
    wordCounts.toStream().to("wordCountTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long()));

    return upperCaseStream;
}

}
```